# How to format currency units combined with other units?

Tags: nombres, typographie, science, unités

If I have a value 25.5 Which of the following is correct?

1. 25,5 $/h
2. 25,5 $ /h

As you can see, I'm stressed out about the space after the currency symbol. What is the usual format for these kinds of units in French-language documents?

Answer (score 2):

25,5 $/h is correct, it means "25,5 dollar per hour".

Comment: To add to that, in french, when it comes to punctuation, there's no space for unit separation. As in m/s, $/h, €/h.. There's a space before the unit, like you used in your example.

Spaces for punctuation follow the rule of 1 after when it has one part (like end-of-sentence dots, commas, dashes, parenthesis, etc.), and 1 space before and after when it has two parts (as in ':', ';', etc.). That space before punctuation is insecable.

If there's multiple punctuation marks following one another, there's only a space after the last one.